# Limit Area to 10km from the center point - OpenLayers Map

Tags: maps, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers Library for Showing some specific points on Map. I want to show only 10km area from the center point. Can any one help me doing this?

Here is the snippet of my code.

```js
 var map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        }),
        vectorLayer
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new View({
        center: transform([19.83752162, 52.09696925], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 12,

      })
    });
```

Comment: You can set a maxResolution option on the view (the value you need will depend on your map szie)

Comment: maxResolution prevents zooming out but still allows panning.  If you never want to pan than 10km you can set an extent option on the view (in OpenLayers 6 only).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you have to do some pre-processing before map initializing.

1- Make feature from center coordinates.

```
let pointFeature = new ol.Feature(
    new ol.geom.Point(transform([19.83752162, 52.09696925], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
);
```

2- Get extent of above created feature.

```
let poitnExtent = pointFeature.getGeometry().getExtent();
```

3- Buffer the extent to your desired radius.

```
let bufferedExtent = new ol.extent.buffer(poitnExtent, raduis goes here (In meters));
```

4- Use this buffered extent to initialize map.

```
var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: transform([19.83752162, 52.09696925], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    extent: bufferedExtent,
    zoom: 12,

  })
});
```

Comment: You can even skip creating the Feature since the geometry alone is enough, something like:
`const pointExtent = new ol.geom.Point(transform([19.83752162, 52.09696925], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')).getExtent();`

Comment: beware of distances in 3857, they are not reliable, especially in northern latitudes as in the OP